# How to add Web Pages 2 with razor syntax in an empty web application project in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I want to create simple Web Pages 2 applications.

I want to use the `File->New->Project->Empty Web Application` and not the `File->New-Web Site`.

After i create a new empty web application i cant add a .cshtml file..

The only way that i could do it is:

- Nuget -> Install Web Pages 2 with razor libraries
- Add->New->Razor MVC View

I am NOT putting the .cshtml file in Views directory. Instead i leave it in root and name it Default.cshtml

Is THIS really the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Pages 2 applications are Web *Sites*, not Web *Applications*, so you should do the following:

```
File » New Web Site » ASP.NET Web Site (Razor 2)
```

Comment: Correct and that is what i thought so but i am reading everywhere discouraging notes about NOT using the web site approach in Visual Studio. So i suppose that the only way to go is with Web Site template?

Comment: Those notes relate to Web Forms apps where you have a choice, but you do not have a choice for MVC or Web Pages. MVC are Web application only, whereas Web Pages are Web Site only. Each have their pro's and cons. Personally, I use WebMatrix to create the site and then open it in VS for IntelliSense, debugging etc.

Comment: Ok i think i understood. Do i have to convert the web site directory to application in IIS in order to run?

Comment: Nope. If you create the site using WebMatrix, it will manage IIS Express for you. If you want to deploy the site, you can use the IIS management tools on the server to add a new web site and browse to the containing folder - just like a classic ASP, PHP or static HTML site.

Comment: i tried to install it as a new virtual directory to an IIS 7.5 but it didnt work without converting the dir to application...But that is another question here after i investigate further..thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can do this. I've done it this way.

Open VS 2013

From the main menu: File > New > Project

Under Installed Templates

Select
  Templates
    Visual C# (or VB)
      Web
     (do not select VS 2012)

Select ASP.NET Web Application from the list of projects on the right of screen

Next Screen - Select Empty Project, Check Webforms

Run once, get error for no default page

Only files in project
  Global.asax
  Web.config

Select "Project" in Solution Explorer
    (do not select the Solution)
    Select Manage NuGet Packages

```
Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages
Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages Data (Important! Includes WebMatrix dlls)
```

Add Layout and View pages
  Notice the code is recognized as an error

If you run, you get a Server Error that ViewBag does not exist
  Change ViewBag to Page

Run again. You should be able to develop like standard web pages but with Razor and no viewstate.

That should be it. I've been doing this since VS 2012 and love the results. 
I contacted Scott H. at MS about adding this as a project type. Didn't get
far. He didn't see the point in doing a project this way. IMHO, I disagree.